# Why do mobs die in mined quarry?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm asking this just out of curiosity. After installing `QuarryPlus` on my Minecraft 1.6.4 I have noticed that all mobs which were in mining area (quarry was place in the Nether - there were tons of mobs!!!) before the end of mining just died and I have found a LOT of experience orbs there. Why? What has killed them?

Comment: I don't know much about the Quarry, but isn't it possible that monsters are jumping into the quarry and dying that way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dropped experience orbs have nothing to do with mobs dieing in there. The QuarryPlus drops xp for the ores it mines (for the ores that give xp such as coal and nether quartz.

Since the chunks are in some weird state of loaded/not-loaded the item dissappear timer doesn't tick down and the xp piles up. The moment you arrive you then find whole masses of xp laying around.

Comment: But still, why do they die?

Comment: Are you sure they died? Didn't they just despawn as normal?

Answer (score 2):

**The mobs despawned**. Hostile mobs will despawn immediately if there is no player within 128 blocks, and have a 1/800 chance of despawning if there is no player within 32 blocks for more than 30 seconds. Mobs don't spawn on bedrock either, so it is perfectly normal for a quarry hole to have no mobs in it later.

As for the explanation as to where the experience orbs came from, Nether Quartz drops experience when mined. QuarryPlus drops experience when mining, and the experience doesn't despawn, since item entities follow different despawn rules.

Comment: The despawn rule for item entities is in general 5 minutes in a loaded chunk = despawned. But the chunks for Quarry+ aren't loaded somehow (this can be seen by using the "loaded chunks" overlay in Opis). So the xp accumulates. Although they need to be loaded for the quarry to be able to work. It's weird how it works.

Comment: @Arperum I think they're in a state of "redstone's loaded" - chunk mechanics are weird, so *sometimes* some redstone stuff will take place when a chunk isn't loaded. I think that might be what's happening here.